# Throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException and I don't understand how

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

the code in this class is throwing an "indexOutOfBounds exception". I don't understand why its throwing that, I'm just trying to loop through each row, and each column, then assign each column to a variable. For more clarification, initializeArray is a regular 2D ARRAY, and initializedArray is an ARRAYLIST.

```
//Array to initialize course list (format is first name, last name, student number}
//This is the array that I will be using to store each row into the ArrayList
      String [] [] initializeArray = 
          {{"Hasan","Ahmed","462948"},
           {"Abdul","Alvi","764226"},
           {"Omar","Askalany","719049"},
           {"Harsim","Grewal","438629"},
           {"Anis","Habib","576510"},
           {"Hamiz","Hasan","621802"},
           {"Bilal","Hussain","417440"},
           {"Mazhar","Jabakhan","603544"},
           {"Tharsh","Kamalan","447615"},
           {"Rohan","Kanjani","443604"}};
      

      //Setting up an ordered collection class of Students using the values in initializeArray
      //The parameter "Student", is a class. Student(String firstName, String lastName, String stuNum)
      ArrayList<Student> initializedArray = new ArrayList<Student>();
      
      //for every row in initializeArray
      for(int row = 0; row<initializeArray.length; row++)
      {
        //for every column in initializeArray
        for(int col = 0; col<initializeArray[row].length; col++)
        {
          String temp = initializeArray[row][col];      //set the first element to temp
          String temp2 = initializeArray[row][col+1];   //set the second element to temp2
          String temp3 = initializeArray[row][col+2];   //set the third element to temp3, this is where the run-time error is happening, but its happening with the other temp vars as well
          initializedArray.add(new Student(temp, temp2, temp3));
        }
      }
      System.out.println(initializedArray);
```

Comment: I don't think you need the inner loop. Doing this should be sufficient but likely a bad practice since there is hardcoding. Maybe check if the length of inner array has enough element first: `String temp = initializeArray[row][0];String temp2 = initializeArray[row][1];...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your index is out of bounds just like the exception says.

Have a look at `initializeArray[row][col+1];` and the loop condition `col<initializeArray[row].length`. What happens when `col` has the value `initializeArray[row].length - 1` and you add 1? The index is outside the allowed range [0, initializeArray[row].length-1].

In your case you know that there are only 3 columns, so you probably just mean `initializeArray[row][0]`, `initializeArray[row][1]` etc.

In other cases you actually might need to loop over an array and you might want to addess indices after the "current" one (e.g. `array[i+1]`) but in thos cases you need to make sure that the loop condition takes that into account or that you check inside the loop.

Assume you want to do some calculation based on the elements at `i` as well as `i-1` and `i+1` in one iteration. In that case your loop should be:

```
for(int i = 1;i < array.length - 1; i++)
```

That way you make sure that `i-1` is never < 0 and `i+1` is never >= `array.length`.

**Update**
As per the question in the comment, here's how you could iterate over the array to print (and for education purposes I'll use a foreach loop) - please note that this is an exception, don't add other questions here but post a new one to keep things simple:

```
for(Student student : initializedArray) {
  System.out.println(student.getGivenName() + " " + student.getFamiliyName() + " " + student.getNumber());
}
```

Of course this assumes your `Student` class has those methods.

To make your life easier, override `toString()`:

```
class Student {
  ... //other code

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return givenName + " " + familyName + " " + number;
  }
}
```

Then when printing the list you should get something like "Hasan Ahmed 462948, Abdul Alvi 764226, ...". Using the foreach loop would then look like this:

```
for(Student student : initializedArray) {
  System.out.println(student);
}
```

Comment: I just have one more question, how can I print out the values in the ArrayList after?. Like it should be ordered, the first student's first name, last name, student number, then new line and the second student's first name, last name etc. until the last student is reached.

Comment: @Anonymous well you can iterate over the outer array, get the elements from the inner array and print accordingly (or iterate over the list only :) ). I'll add an example.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I think I get what you are saying but the console is just printing out weird values. Such as, "Student@1614@e23".

Comment: @Anonymous I've added the example. Those "weird" characters you get are the instance's class and id, i.e. the output of `Object.toString()`. You need to override that method to get more meaningful output.

Comment: I see. So, ArrayLists are far more different then regular arrays then I originally thought. Anyways, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Anonymous well, ArrayLists are lists that internally use arrays. They behave very similarly but have their differences (e.g. an ArrayList can "grow" by allocating a new array if necessary). Looping and printing would still be more or less the same.

Comment: I apologize but what can I do if I wanted to print out only a certain index of the arraylist?

Comment: @Anonymous sorry, didn't see that question till now. If you want to print only data at one index then try a normal for loop like `for(int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++)` (if needed at all) and use the `get(index)` method of the list. Note that you might want to grab a tutorial on those basic things as that will make it easier for you to learn them instead of asking here. Also you might want to improve your searching skills as programmers will have to do a lot of searching for new stuff (new technologies, concepts etc.).

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is to remove the second loop and inside first your code will be like this :

```
String temp = initializeArray[row][0]; 
String temp2 = initializeArray[row][1];
String temp3 = initializeArray[row][2];  
initializedArray.add(new Student(temp, temp2, temp3));
```

because when you loop inside **initializeArray[row]** and when you become to col equal to **initializeArray[row].length** the +1 and +2 will be out of bounds

Comment: thank you for your answer, I understand this whole thing a bit better.

Comment: how can I print out just one element of this ArrayList. When I try initializedArray.get(1), it prints out gibberish. Random chars.

Comment: use `initializedArray.get(index)` and **index** is an int number between 0 and initializedArray.size()

Comment: i already tried that but it prints out gibberish, or the hash value of the index, not the actual string.

Answer (score 0):

I would do one loop with

```
if (initializeArray[row].length > 2) {
    initializedArray.add(new Student(initializeArray[row][0], initializeArray[row][1], initializeArray[row][2]));
}
```

Otherwise, the condition for the inner loop should be

```
col < initializeArray[row].length - 2
```

given that you are accessing  `initializeArray[row][col + 2]`.

Comment: how can I print out one element of the ArrayList? Essentially just one student and his information.